# How do I go about removing all digits and all punctuations in a string?

Tags: javascript

How do I go about removing all digits and all punctuations in a string using regex?
For example:
  From `Eric-Has555-Books` to `EricHasBooks`

I am trying to use String.replace(), but my regex below doesn't work:

```
str = 'Eric-Has555-Books'
reg = /[0-9]-/g;
str.replace(reg, '');
```

Comment: What about keeping only alpha characters?

Comment: You were close, the `-` should be inside the `[]`: `/[0-9\-]/g`. There's no need to escape it, but I prefer to do it for readability purpose.

Comment: That's more helpful this way.  Thanks,  Karl-André Gagnon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[^a-z]` which says "Remove everything that isn't a letter". This is also known as [`Negated Character Classes`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

```js
let r = 'Eric-Has555-Books'.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '')

console.log(r)
```

Comment: That question is nine years old and SO standards were different back then. Although I just downvoted it and flagged it as too broad. Thanks.